# Nested Loop Over Two Files

Tags: linux, shell

I have two test files, the first one contains a 3rd party names, the second file contains a message status like sent, failed, technical errors, etc.

I want to search in a log file for each 3rd party name (from first file) and get count of each message status (listed in file 2)

example of **1st file.txt** (3rd party names)

```
BNF_IPL
one97
pajwok
RadioAzadi
SPICDIGITAL
U2OPIA
UNIFUN
UNIFUNRS
vectracom
VNTAF
YRMP
INFOTT
```

second file.txt (message status):

```
success
partial
failed
Error absentSubscriber
UnknownSubscriber
smDeliveryFailure
userSpecificReason
CallBarred
systemFailure
```

my goal is to produce a report contains total status for each 3rd party. something like

```
          sent     | failed   | TechErrpr |    Absent | subscriber 
 IBM        someValue  someValue   someValue   someValue   someValue  
Microsoft   someValue  someValue   someValue   someValue   someValue
Oracle      someValue  someValue   someValue   someValue   someValue
google      someValue  someValue   someValue   someValue   someValue
```

To get the values i will grep those names and status in a log file and get the totals. for that i am trying to use nested loop but with no luck.something like:

```
for ((i = 0; i <  wc -l  3rdPList.txt ; i++)); do

for ((j = i; j < wc -l status.txt ; j++)); do
     grep 3rdPList.txt logFile | grep status.txt | wc -l > outputFile.txt
    echo $st[j]
  done
done
```

example of the log file:

```
2018-10-30 00:07:19,640 DEBUG [org.mobicents.smsc.library.CdrGenerator] 2018-10-29 14:42:45,789 +0430,588,5,0,93706315646,1,1,temp_failed,BNF_IPL,26674477,0702700006,412012004908984,null,ایید.,Error absentSubscriber after MtForwardSM Request: MAPErrorMessageAbsentSubscriber []
2018-10-30 00:07:41,034 DEBUG [org.mobicents.smsc.library.CdrGenerator] 2018-10-29 16:21:27,260 +0430,588,5,0,0700375593,1,1,temp_failed,BNF_IPL,27008401,null,null,null,عدد1 را به588 ارسال ,AbsentSubscriber response from HLR: MAPErrorMessageAbsentSubscriber []
```

Comment: Where's the log file?

Comment: it is just a log file contains 3rd party name and message status along with so many other information

Comment: Please show a sample log file and what the expected output would be when using that file.

Comment: I have added a sample of the log file to the original post

Comment: `IBM`, `Google` and `Oracle` don't seem to be in the log file?

Comment: the expected values is the total number of each status like total number of "failed", "success" , ...etc ... I have mentioned an example in my post

Comment: IBM, Google and Oracle are just example

Comment: the real names of 3rd party are like BNF_IPL. as shown on the sample log

Comment: We aren't psychic! How can we know that `BNF_IPL` buried in a bunch of commas is similar to `Google`??? How many lines are there in your *"3rd party"* file and how many in your *"message status"* file? Is the message status always in the same place - immediately before the company name?

Comment: I have updated my post to show the content of status.txt and 3rdpary.txt files. the message status field is always before company name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does pretty much what you ask, but I didn't work too much on pretty formatting!

```
{ sed 's/^/1,/' 1.txt; sed 's/^/2,/' 2.txt; cat log.txt; } | awk -F, '$1==1{c=substr($0,3);cc[c]++;next} $1==2{s=substr($0,3); ss[s]++;next} {s=$10;c=$11;res[c SEP s]++} END{for(s in ss){printf("%s ",s)};printf("\n");for(c in cc){printf("%s ",c);for(s in ss){printf("%d ",res[c SEP s]+0)}printf("\n")}}'
```

**Sample Output**

```
systemFailure temp_failed CallBarred userSpecificReason smDeliveryFailure UnknownSubscriber Error absentSubscriber partial success 
pajwok 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
SPICDIGITAL 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
YRMP 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
UNIFUN 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 
U2OPIA 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
UNIFUNRS 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
RadioAzadi 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
one97 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
BNF_IPL 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
VNTAF 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
INFOTT 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
vectracom 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If you want to understand it, try running the parts separately. So, for the first part, I prefix all the company names by a `1` so that `awk` can differentiate them from status codes and log lines:

```
sed 's/^/1,/' 1.txt
```

**Output**

```
1,BNF_IPL
1,one97
1,pajwok
1,RadioAzadi
1,SPICDIGITAL
1,U2OPIA
1,UNIFUN
1,UNIFUNRS
1,vectracom
1,VNTAF
1,YRMP
1,INFOTT
```

Then, I prefix all the status messages with a `2` so that `awk` can differentiate those from company names and log lines:

```
sed 's/^/2,/' 2.txt
```

**Output**

```
2,success
2,partial
2,temp_failed
2,Error absentSubscriber
2,UnknownSubscriber
2,smDeliveryFailure
2,userSpecificReason
2,CallBarred
2,systemFailure
```

Then I `cat` the log file into `awk`:

```
cat log.txt
```

The `awk` can be written across multiple lines and commented:

```
{ sed ...; sed ...; cat ...; } | awk -F, '
    $1==1 {c=substr($0,3); cc[c]++; next}  # Process company name in "1.txt", "c" holds name, "cc[]" is an array of names
    $1==2 {s=substr($0,3); ss[s]++; next}  # Process status code in "2.txt, "s" holds status, "ss[]" is an array of statuses
          {s=$10; c=$11; res[c SEP s]++}   # Process line from log, status is field 10, company is field 11. Increment results array "res[]"
    END   {       
            # Print line of status codes
            for(s in ss){printf("%s ",s)};
            printf("\n");
            for(c in cc){printf("%s ",c);
               for(s in ss){printf("%d ",res[c SEP s]+0)}printf("\n")}
    }'
```

`SEP` is just a separator to fake 2-D arrays.

Comment: This is really brilliant and great solution ... simple and perfect. if it is possible to add a line separator after the header (i.e. the status) to separate the header and the values below it

Comment: Sure, copy the line that says `printf("\n");` and paste it in a second time below the first.

Comment: You can change the `printf("%s")` to make the fields, say, 20 characters fixed width with `printf("%-20s")` if you want to align things in a table.

Comment: that's really great.. i got another requirement. (beside status in col 10, I have to add some status which present in col17. col 17 contains message returns from HLR. ex. `UnknownSubscriber response from HLR: MAPErrorMessageUnknownSubscriber []` i want to get count of  UnknownSubscriber  for example